# module.exports = Promise.all not working inside tests

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, chai

I want to just make sure that my server is running before I create PR's locally to test that nothing is broken.

**worker.js**

My server exports a promise

```
module.exports = Promise.all([
    hbsPartialsLoaded,
])
.then(() => {
    let server;

    if (!isTestEnvironment) {
        server = app.listen(config.port);
    }

    return { server, app };
});
```

**tests**

```
let { expect, request } = require('chai')
    .use(require('chai-http'))
    .use(require('chai-cheerio'));
const config = require('../../app/config');
const worker = require('../../app/worker');

describe('server response', function () {
    worker.then(() => {
        before(function () {
            server.listen(config.port);
        });

        it('should return 200', function (done) {
            request.get(`http://localhost:${config.port}`, function (err, res, body){
                expect(res.statusCode).to.equal(200);
                done();
            });
        });

        after(function () {
            worker.close();
        });
    })
});
```

**Running Tests**

```
 NODE_ENV=test mocha --timeout 20000 --recursive test/ --compilers js:babel-core/register



  0 passing (1ms)
```

My tests are never run. How can I get it so I wait for `sever.js` to finish its promises before the tests are run?

Comment: did you try putting `worker.then` before `describe`? also you don't need to call `done()` if you are using `expect` from chai

Comment: Same difference ye, with `worker.then` wrapping describe. Good point, removed the `done()`

Answer (score 1):

You didn't export the promise correctly, so the calling is bad, because you may not get callback if the `require("worker.js")` finished before calling `.then`, it should be `worker().then` not `worker.then`, but that's not the only problem.

The `worker.js` should return a function that launches the `Promise.all`. So change the `module.exports = Promise.all...` to `module.exports = () => Promise.all...`

Use `before` to launch the server and call `it` synchronously. Inside `it` you can use the asynchronous functions as you want.

The `server.listen` has a callback on second argument, that tells you when it finishes, so you can use promise and resolve it there.

An example:

```
var expect = require('chai').expect;

describe('x', () => { 
    before(() => new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(resolve, 500)));

    it('should work', (done) => setTimeout(() => expect(0).to.be.above(0), 500));
});
```

Better example for your case:

```
var expect = require('chai').expect;

var app = require('express')();

describe('x', () => { 
    before(() => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        app.listen(3000, () => {
            console.log('The server launched');
            resolve();
        });
    }));

    it('should work', (done) => {
        console.log('I got called after the server got launched! :)');
        setTimeout(() => expect(1).to.be.above(0), 500)
    });
});
```

Comment: I can see that having promises does work then.... However, I need them to be resolved from an external file.

Comment: @JamieHutber if the `worker.js` is just returning a promise with server, then it's simple to implement. `return new Promise((resolve, reject) => require('worker.js')().then(obj => obj.server.listen(3000, resolve)))` inside `before` should do the job.

Comment: It is indeed, this is what I changed to get it working `    before(() => {
        return new Promise(( resolve, reject ) => worker.then(( obj, err ) => {
            if(err) {console.info(err); return err;}
            server = obj.app.listen(config.port, resolve);
        }))
    });`

Comment: @JamieHutber great, although I think you shouldn't launch the `Promise.all` just after you required the file, doing `module.exports = () => Promise.all` would be better. I edited the answer, hope it's easier to understand now.

Answer (score 0):

`it()` functions should be called directly inside `describe()`. Nested inside a promise doesn't read well nor follow the standard testing process

```
let { expect, request } = require('chai')
    .use(require('chai-http'))
    .use(require('chai-cheerio'));
const config = require('../../app/config');
const worker = require('../../app/worker');

describe('server response', function () {
    before(function () {
        server.listen(config.port);
    });

    it('should return 200', function (done) {
        worker.then(() => {
            request.get(`http://localhost:${config.port}`, function (err, res, body){
                expect(res.statusCode).to.equal(200);
                done();
            });
        })
    });

    after(function () {
        worker.close();
    });
});
```